# Bootstrap modal inside code is multiplying every time a new modal opens

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

Hello so I created a room password validation for the chat that I built and I used Bootstrap's 4 modal to show the user the password input.

[image]

I am using jQuery to open the modal like so `$("#password-validation").modal();`. It works great. But after you close the modal, reopen it and submit the input, the code inside the "if the user clicks the enter button" executes multiple times instead of on.

```
// #room-password-btn is the enter button
$("#room-password-btn").click(function(){ 
  console.log("Execute")
});
```

An example: so if you (open the modal button and close the modal)* 3 and then click the enter button you'd see in the console:

```
// first open and close
// second open and close
Execute // third open, enter
Execute
Execute
```

A working model of the question: https://codepen.io/PachUp/pen/LYGQozz (try to close it and press enter and you'll see multiple messages instead of one, the more you close the more messages you'll see. I believe that if I fix that then the question would be solved).

Modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="password-validation" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="room-password-val-aria" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header text-center">
        <h4 class="modal-title w-100 font-weight-bold">Enter the room password</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body mx-3">
        <div class="md-form mb-5">
          <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right">Room password</label>
          <input class="form-control" id="room-password-val">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer d-flex justify-content-center">
        <button class="btn btn-default" id="room-password-btn">Enter</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Full JS:

```
    corrent_pass = false;
    room_pass = ""
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/validate",
        data: new_room,
        success: function(pass){
            room_pass = pass; // pass is the room password
        }
    });
    
    console.log("room pass: " + room_pass)
    console.log(room_pass.length)
    if(room_pass != "False"){ 
        $("#password-validation").modal('toggle');
        $('#password-validation').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
            $('#room-password-val').trigger('focus');
            $("#room-password-btn").mousedown(function(){
                console.log("Execute")
                user_password = $("#room-password-val").val()
                console.log(user_password)
                console.log(room_pass)
                if(user_password == room_pass){
                    corrent_pass = false
                    $("#messages").html("");
                    $("#password-validation .close").click()
                    toastr["success"]("Entering you into the room!", "Corrent password")
                    console.log("Joining a room")
                    socket.emit('leave', {"room" : room})
                    socket.emit("join", {"room" : new_room})
                    room = new_room
                }
                else{
                    toastr["error"]("Sorry, you have entered the wrong password. Try again.", "Wrong password")
                }
            });
        });
    }
    else{
        console.log("no password")
        $("#messages").html("");
        console.log("Joining a room")
        socket.emit('leave', {"room" : room})
        socket.emit("join", {"room" : new_room})
        var room_msg = "You have joined " + new_room
        toastr["success"](room_msg, "Room joined")
        room = new_room
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please share your currently working code?

Comment: @ShahnawazHossan I did. I didn't want to share it because I think the entire part of the js code(that is related to the question) is relevant but if it helps you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dont_panic/dzg3qhf9/) (I replaced your `toastr` stuff with simple `alert()`s, and commented out the `socket` stuff).

The problem is that you are adding event listeners based on repeatable user activity.  For example:

```
if(room_pass != "False"){ 
    // ...
    // Adding an event handler for the modal shown event based on 
    // previous user activity
    $('#password-validation').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
        // ... 
        // Adding another event handler, inside a previous event handler
        $("#room-password-btn").mousedown(function(){
```

But adding an event handler does not replace any previous event handler that was already attached - they stack up, even if it is exactly the same handler for exactly the same event.  So if you repeat the conditions that added the handler, you'll add a new one on top of the old one.  And they will all run together when triggered.

Every time you close your modal, you add another handler to do something when it opens, which in turn adds another handler to do something on `mousedown`.  The first time you close it, you have one set of handlers to do stuff.  If you open it and close it again, you add a new set, and they will *all* run when the event is triggered.

It is a better approach to add your handlers just once, independent of any user behaviour or conditions.  That way you can be sure they are attached just once.  If the actions you want the handler to take depend on what the user did, you should to test the state within the handler, not the other way around.

So in this case:

```
// Add event handlers, independent of any other activity
$('#password-validation').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    console.log("Closed")
    // ...
});

$('#password-validation').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    $('#room-password-val').trigger('focus');
});

$("#room-password-btn").mousedown(function(){
    // ...
});

// ... 

if (room_pass != "False") {
    $("#password-validation").modal('toggle');

} else{
    console.log("Joining a room")
    // ...
}
```

Note you can also [remove handlers using `.off()`](https://api.jquery.com/off/) if you need, and in some complex cases that might be the way to go - adding and removing handlers as state changes.  But there's no need for such extra complication here.

### Update

From the comments the actual problem is in some code not shown which handles a user click on a menu of chat rooms, which is dynamically populated from the DB.  I described the general case of how to handle this above - test the state inside the event handler, so you can take appropriate action.  Here's an example - not based on your actual HTML or code as I don't have that.

HTML example:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="/rooms/chat1" data-room="room1">Chat 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="/rooms/chat2" data-room="room2">Chat 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="/rooms/chat3" data-room="room3">Chat 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
// Password will be set in AJAX below
var room_pass;

// Register a handler on .dropdown-menu, even if it has no elements
// on page load.  Every click will be filtered to check it it was 
// on an <a>.  This way you can dynamically add contents to the menu,
// and still handle those clicks.
$('.dropdown-menu').on('click', 'a', function(e) {

    // Don't actually follow the link 
    e.preventDefault();

    // In the handler, "$(this)" is the event target.  So you can 
    // find which link was clicked like this:
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    
    // Or its text:
    var text = $(this).text();

    // Or maybe it has data attributes
    var room = $(this).data('room');

    // Not sure I understand your comments but maybe you want something
    // like this, where you pass something about the clicked link to the
    // AJAX query
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/validate",
        data: room,
        success: function(pass) {
            room_pass = pass;
        }
    });
});
```

Minor side notes:

- Using `mousedown` to handle the password entry means a user cannot use their keyboard to submit.  This is not good user experience, it looks like a form so hitting enter should work, plus of course there is the accessibility concern.  To fix this you'd need to actually add a `<form>` in your modal, and replace the `mousedown` handler with a `submit` handler on that form.
- Typo in `corrent_pass`, probably meant to be `correct`?  Not really important as long as it is used consistently, but typos are a good way to give your future self much confusion! :-)

Comment: I understand and it may worked in the model but it's still a problem in my code that I am working on. That's of course after I changed your code according to what you said I should do.

Comment: @Patch It sounds like you have another problem somewhere, the JSFiddle I linked to solves the problem you describe, right?  If you can update your question and/or Codepen with *simplified* code showing the problem, I can have a look. Please do try to simplify it, remove stuff that is not relevant to this problem, make it easier for us to get your code running (eg the socket stuff, toastr stuff ... ).

Comment: I didn't "simplified" it. the only real difference is that I first check if the user clicked in a room from the drop-down menu P.S the 2 little notes that you added aren't really relevant...

Comment: @Patch I know you didn't simplify it, I am asking if you please can for any updates :-) If you can make it simpler for us to get your code running, it is simpler to help.  The notes are just suggestions, that's why I called them **minor notes**! :-) You can use them or not.

Comment: `$(".dropdown-menu").on('click', '.room', function(event){` I call this line before I do the code that I showed there. It's kind of hard to demo it because I am taking the rooms from the db and I need to create the drop-down menu. But basically I have that before the code in the JSFiddle. I need the code to be inside the `dropdown-menu` call because I am using the event.

Comment: The problem is the `$('#password-validation').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {$("#password-validation").modal();});`. if I use it in my code it works well because it is working with the exact same modal. I wrote it in a comment , that it's not a part of my code, it's just to show the `closing` of the modal. In my actual code I don't force the user to open the modal every time the modal closes. perhaps you can update your question according to what I said.

Comment: For your dropdown, attach the handler to some parent element that exists before you populate the menu.  Eg (just guessing) if you are adding `<li>` elements to your menu from the DB, you can still use `.dropdown-menu` for the event handler, and it can be outside any user-related code ...

Comment: I described this in my answer - `If the actions you want the handler to take depend on what the user did, you should to test the state within the handler`.  So in the handler, work out what item was clicked.  If you can update your question with your menu HTML, I can update my answer with an example.

Comment: I fixed it... I had to create a global variable though...

Comment: @Patch I added some example code to find which menu the user clicks. I don't know what your real code looks like but it shows the idea.

Comment: What you did is the same as what I did. That causes the bug

Comment: That's what I am trying to explain the user password COMES from the room name.I wrote that I need to make an ajax call to the backend to get the password of the room. Handle that and it'd soulve it.

Comment: Yeah I told you it has to be a global var, that's kind of how I did it too. Anyway it worked so I'll bounty you when I can. Thank! +1

Answer (score 1):

You can solve that problem by one line of code using `off` right `after your #password-validation` event listener what it basically does it unbind/removes the event listener after it is triggered so that you don't have a stack of events firing after you open your modal again

```
$('#password-validation').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
$('#room-password-val').trigger('focus');
$("#password-validation").off("shown.bs.modal");
```

here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sven07/xn0w1y2j/)

Comment: The `$("#password-validation").modal('toggle');` needs to be inside the `if(room_pass != "False"){ ` if I put both of the `$("#password-validation").off("shown.bs.modal");` and `$("#password-validation").modal('toggle');`  the `off` one just cancels the `modal('toggle')` one

Comment: here is the code exactly as you posted it on codepen , [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sven07/bjLdzfun/)

Comment: Yeah but it reopens because in the code when you close the modal it reopens, I said that's not how it's actually what I am doing it's just to show you the problem.

Comment: You didn't mention none of this in your enquiry about the problem above, and the fact that it reopens it's because in your code/question you said it's for "testing purpose",In my first code if you pay enough attention I removed the reopen behaviour and mimicked a real life scenario by using a button, so perhaps you should be more clear and precise in the future

Comment: I actually did, I commented it in my code. If I would of explain it in my question no one would understand. My question couldn't be clearer, You just looked inside of the model file when I did it your way it just closed right away. Anyway someone else already answered. +1.

Answer (score 0):

You've checked whether your modal is shown or not right after this line **`$("#password-validation").modal();`** by doing this:

```js
console.log($('#password-validation').is(':visible')) // false every time
console.log($('#password-validation').hasClass('in')) // false every time
```

So these two lines are executing first before showing the modal. You can check this after modal is shown by this event:

```js
$('#password-validation').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    // will only come inside after the modal is shown
    console.log($('#password-validation').is(':visible')) // true every time if shown
    console.log($('#password-validation').hasClass('show')) // true every time if shown
});
```

**And look carefully, `$('#password-validation').hasClass('in')` this will not work in `bootstrap 4`. So you can check through this way that I've mentioned in the event whether the modal is shown or not.**

This would solve your problem I guess.

Comment: Well that would soulve my note that I did but I don't think it'll fix the entire thing.

Comment: Yeah that fixed my note but the actual problem was not fixed.

Comment: Multiple times execution is happening because your modal is not destroying properly. Just dispose your modal every time after you hit the enter by doing this **`$('#password-validation').modal('dispose')`**

Comment: Is it printing(`Execute`) multiple times on the third time, after you close the modal and reopen it when you dispose the modal?

Comment: Yes. And what you said with the dispose didn't work. "after you close the modal and reopen" yes and then in the third time you click the enter button. I put the dispote after the user hits the enter button and it does `modal.js:282 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'focus' of null` `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'backdrop' of null` when i try to close it.

Comment: Try `$('#password-validation').modal('hide')` this one and let me know.

Comment: So what do you suggest?

Comment: I didn't find anything else to see this code actually. It might have other issue. Since the modal is shown right after the button is clicked, I don't have any idea why `Execute` is printing multiple times. It's hard to say without seeing the full code.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap now has a `.one` method that will only fire the callback once on the trigger and unbind it afterwards.

```
$('#password-validation').one('shown.bs.modal', function () {
   $('#room-password-val').trigger('focus');
}
```